# Ubuntu 14.10 installation fails on Asus Zenbook UX305FA

Tags: system-installation, 14.10, live-usb, asus

I have attempted to install Ubuntu 14.10 on my new Asus Zenbook UX305FA. Every time I attempt it, it sticks at the Security Key section. The laptop came equipped with Windows 8.1, and I erased it to have a solely Linux machine. I am somewhat new to Linux, but this is what I can tell you:

I did the checksum and it matched (found on these forums).
The Live USB works
I went into my terminal via the Live USB and typed sudo lshw. Here is the full output - I don't completely know what I'm looking at, I just saw on another thread where someone requested the output of this command.

I don't understand what is going wrong. I just want my new laptop to work. My older laptop works just fine with the same OS. It's an HP 2000.

Thank you all for any potential help. I'm in dire straits.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw
ubuntu                    
    description: Notebook
    product: UX305FA (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    serial: F1N0CJ098316048
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=UX sku=ASUS-NotebookSKU uuid=09A74FFC-4DB3-4DE0-80D9-16BA9AA11401
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: UX305FA
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: BSN12345678901234567
       slot: MIDDLE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: UX305FA.206
          date: 12/16/2014
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6400KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: e
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: f
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
     *-cache:2
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 10
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
     *-cache:3
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 11
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 4MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Processor 5Y10 CPU @ 0.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 12
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Processor 5Y10 CPU @ 0.80GHz
          serial: NULL
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 14
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             vendor: 0000
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             vendor: 0000
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 08
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 08
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:62 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 08
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:65 memory:f711c000-f711ffff
        *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Broadwell-U Camarillo Device
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 08
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7110000-f7117fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:60 memory:f7100000-f710ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:63 memory:f7124000-f712401f
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:64 memory:f7118000-f711bfff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:58
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:59 memory:f7000000-f70fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7265
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 59
                serial: 60:57:18:38:2c:55
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-23-generic firmware=25.222.9.0 ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:66 memory:f7000000-f7001fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:61 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7122000-f71227ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7121000-f71210ff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7120000-f7120fff
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: SanDisk SD7SN3Q2
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 0002
             serial: 144819400233
             size: 238GiB (256GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=5c52202f-0bab-49d1-9c31-f5be9f65ebaf sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: FAT32
                serial: 3d40-5217
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
           *-volume:1
                description: EFI partition
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: 1.0
                serial: 7df445a3-afb6-4d1c-90d2-6057ba6ba872
                size: 244MiB
                capabilities: extended_attributes ext2 initialized
                configuration: filesystem=ext2 lastmountpoint=/media/ubuntu/7df445a3-afb6-4d1c-90d2-6057ba6ba872 modified=2015-05-02 23:03:26 mounted=2015-05-02 22:42:30 state=clean
           *-volume:2
                description: EFI partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                serial: 69ac6686-846f-44dd-82dc-20aaca622151
                size: 237GiB
                capacity: 237GiB
                width: 512 bits
                capabilities: encrypted luks initialized
                configuration: bits=512 cipher=aes filesystem=luks hash=sha1 mode=xts-plain64 version=1
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          bus info: usb@1:2
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             size: 14GiB (15GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=00016919
           *-volume
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: SYSLINUX
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /cdrom
                version: FAT32
                serial: 1a0d-0f62
                size: 14GiB
                capacity: 14GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to disable secure boot and uefi in the bios, then make sure "legacy" boot is enabled.

Hope that helps.